# serve 2 different apps with nginx in the same url but different paths

Tags: vue.js, nginx, url, path, frontend

i have 2 vue js app. im trying to serve theirs frontend with Nginx in my localhost in the same port that each application would be served in different path in such a way:

localhost/app1 -> /app1/dist/spa;
localhost/app2 -> /app2/dist/spa;

my nginx.conf is look like this:

```
  events {}

    http {
        server {
            listen 80;
            server_name localhost;

            location /app1 {
                alias /app1/dist/spa;
                index index.html;
            }

            location /app2 {
                alias /app2/dist/spa;
                index index.html;
            }
        }
    }
```

my logs are:

**[error] 29#29: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory),
**

how can i achieve this behavior please?